# Dockerizing ReactJS project getting : "command sh -c react-scripts start" error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm

I have a web application that I'm currently dockerzing.

my docker file looks like this:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm config set registry *<URL>*
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm install serve -g

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

and my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "webpack": "4.42.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

**error image link**: [error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLglu.png)

I've looked at the solutions on other posts about this same error but none work for me. I've deleted the node_modules directory and package-lock.json files, then ran npm install.

However, I still get the same error message. Does anyone know what's wrong? Please do let me know. Thank you.

Comment: How are you starting the container?  What's the actual error you get?  You attached an image file to the question; what code generates that?

Comment: the link attached displays the error i am getting, and i use docker build . -t <username> and docker run -it --rm -p port:port <username>